# Exchange data between Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails application which uses different Rails Engines to encapsulate functionality.

I want to exchange data between these Engines.
Is there a possibility to create some kind of public interface offered by the Engine to exchange data which I can use in the other engines / the Host Application? Or should I use some kind of JSON API for the access?

Here's a little example which should show what I mean:
Let's assume I have a "full" Rails application. I also have a user-Engine and a tweet-Engine mounted in this application. Now I want to access data from the user in the tweet-Engine.

Btw. Is there furthermore a way to create associations between Engine-Models?

I'm very glad if somebody can help me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in user engine application write controller action which will return `xml` or `json` and in tweet engine application just use `net:http` to get the data by calling the methods of user engine app

Comment: If it works can you please vote me up in below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this. You can have a shared database where engines have models which access the same database to communicate between each other. See the rails guide for more information http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#using-a-class-provided-by-the-application

The other approach as you said is to build an API, although that it more applicable to separate applications.

Answer (score 1):

in user engine application write controller action which will return `xml` or `json` and in tweet engine application just use `net:http` to get the data by calling the methods of user engine app.

Thank you